# How can I see if a document contains any of a set of words using ML.net?

Tags: ml.net

I am learning ML.net and want to submit the text of a document to see if it contains one or more specific words.  In my example I want to categorize my document with the day of the week.  For example, if it contains the word "Monday" or "first", then I want it to categorize it as "Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a training dataset. This should consist of documents that contain the words you are looking for AND documents that don't. You will need to label these with a column that contains a Yes or No as the ground truth.

Then use the model builder interface and select a classify task.

Best to start with a small training set just to check you have the data in the right format.